# Deploy Spring Integration in Bitnami Stack

Tags: spring, spring-security, tomcat7, spring-webflow, spring-integration

I am stuck with a problem and I can't figure out what is happening...

I have built an rest-api using spring integration. When I deploy the app in my local tomcat 7 everything works OK.

When I deploy it in mi bitnami stack (same tomcat version) and try the same request (changing the host), authentication step is OK but no mapping is found...

***Basic authentication wih Spring Security is well done***

> 2013-07-02 12:12:04,228 DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor -
>   Previously Authenticated:
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@95f956f:
>   Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@36ebcb:
>   Username: user; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true;
>   AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true;
>   AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE;
>   Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details:
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0:
>   RemoteIpAddress: 85.136.69.37; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities:
>   ROLE 2013-07-02 12:12:04,228 DEBUG
>   vote.AffirmativeBased - Voter:
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@346946d5,
>   returned: 1 2013-07-02 12:12:04,228 DEBUG
>   intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor - **Authorization successful**

***Spring Integration mapping is not found***

> 2013-07-02 12:12:04,228 DEBUG intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor -
>   RunAsManager did not change Authentication object 2013-07-02
>   12:12:04,228 DEBUG web.FilterChainProxy -
>   /ptgapi/v1/clients/1/events/400 reached end of additional filter
>   chain; proceeding with original chain 2013-07-02 12:12:04,228 DEBUG
>   support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter - Opening JPA EntityManager in
>   OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter 2013-07-02 12:12:04,229 DEBUG
>   servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'Destiny
>   Customer Information Search Restful Web Service' processing GET request for [//PTG/ptgapi/v1/clients/1/events/400]
>
> 2013-07-02 12:12:04,229 WARN  servlet.PageNotFound - **No mapping
>   found** for HTTP request with URI
>   [//PTG/ptgapi/v1/clients/1/events/400]
>   in DispatcherServlet with name 'Destiny Customer Information Search
>   Restful Web Service'

Any idea what is happening?

**Update**

I have found that Spring Integration is using a double slash (//) in local and a simple slash (/) in bitnami being the same war.

Could be the way Spring Integration splits the URL (local environment is windows and bitnami is Ubuntu)?

### LOCAL

> 2013-07-02 15:31:28,443 DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'Destiny Customer Information Search Restful Web Service' processing GET request for [**/PTG/ptgapi/v1/clients/1/events/400**]
>
> 2013-07-02 15:31:28,449 DEBUG inbound.UriPathHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/ptgapi/v1/clients/1/events/400] are [/ptgapi/{apiVersion}/clients/{clientId}/events/{eventId}]

### BITNAMI

> 2013-07-02 13:37:45,469 DEBUG servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'Destiny Customer Information Search Restful Web Service' processing GET request for [**//PTG/ptgapi/v1/clients/1/events/400**]
>
> 2013-07-02 13:37:45,470 WARN  servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [//PTG/ptgapi/v1/clients/1/events/400] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Destiny Customer Information Search RestfulWeb Service'

Answer (score 0):

I have found that changing servlet-mapping to this one avoid this strange behaviour:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Destiny Customer Information Search Restful Web Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rootCommonPath/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```